# C# checkbox behavior

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have two checkboxes, and I am trying to make one disable the other based on a certain condition.

```
private void chkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (!chkBox1.Checked && chkBox2.Checked)
            {
                chkBox2.Checked = false;
            }
}
```

That condition being that chkBox1 is unchecked and chkBox 2 is checked, as per the if statement. What ends up happening is that `chkBox1.Checked` value also flips from `false` to `true` inside of the `if` despite there being nothing inside of the `if` to change it. I have debugged and looked at the designer code to see if anything in there is causing issues, but I don't see anything. In designer, there is a wire-up statement of

```
this.chkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chkBox1_CheckedChanged);
```

which is obviously needed to get into the method to check the condition and I want `chkBox1`'s `checkChanged` event to go into the condition. I'm new to C#, but not new to debugging, however this has stumped me for several days, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the state of `chkBox1` when you trigger the `CheckedChanged` event?

Comment: remember that clicking on the checkbox (1) will flip its state

Comment: is there similar code in the `chkBox1_CheckedChanged` event?

Comment: @CarloR it can either be checked or unchecked, as it always goes into the checkChanged event when it's checked value is changed, correct?

Comment: @pm100 if `chkBox1.Checked` is unchecked/false what part of the code causes it's Checked value to go to checked/true?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp do you mean `chkBox2_CheckedChanged` event? if so, that event doesn't exists; I may be wrong, but I don't see a reason to define it or why I would need it

Comment: How do you check if the value of `chkBox1.Checked` flips. Does this behavior changes anything in the UI?

Comment: you are triggering this code by clicking on the ckbox1. cthat click will toggle the state, thats what clicking on a check box does

Comment: Your comment… _”What ends up happening is that chkBox1.Checked value also flips from false to true inside of the if despite there being nothing inside of the if to change it.”_ … ? … this makes NO sense. Of course check box 1’s value is going to “change”… the code is “IN” check box 1’s `CheckedChanged` event... “why” would you expect it to “NOT” change? Please clarify what you are wanting to do and include all conditions.

Comment: take all the code out of the click handler. Now click on the check box1, you will see that it flips state on each click

Comment: @Chetan yes, the behavior on the UI acts as if the value of chkBox1 is changed to true when it gets to inside of the `if` statement, but there is nothing defined explicitly inside of the if statement that sets `chkBox1.Checked` to `true`

Comment: @JohnG what part of that statement makes no sense? based on what I see in UI and in debugging, the `chkBox1.Checked` value very clearly gets set to `true` after the single statement `if` condition executes, however there is nothing inside of the `if` that would set it to `true`... the only thing that happens inside the `if` statement is `chkBox2.Checked` being set to `false`

Comment: The part of your sentence that does not make sense is… _”What ends up happening is that chkBox1.Checked value also flips from false to true…”_ … this does not make sense… “why” would you expect it to not flip? The code is “IN” check box 1’s `CheckedChanged` event!

Comment: The only thing I can think of that may be “throwing” you off is in relation to “DEBUGGING” your code. Example, IF you put a breakpoint on the line… `if (!chkBox1.Checked && chkBox2.Checked) …` … then run the code. Then IF you click on check box 1 to go from un-checked to checked… then… when the breakpoint is hit and execution stops… if you look at … `chkBox1.Checked` … it will be TRUE… HOWEVER… while still on the breakpoint… if you look at check box 1 in the form… it will be “UN-CHECKED” which “appears” to be a contradiction considering `chkBox1.Checked` … is showing as TRUE.

Comment: The reason for this is because WHEN the `chkBox1_CheckedChanged` event fires… the UI has NOT yet “checked” the check box… it will do this AFTER the code in the checked changed event executes and exits.